# Xamarin Forms not creating the expected return types from a Webservice

Tags: c#, android, ios, web-services, xamarin

I am using Visual Studio 2013 for all dev work.

I have an existing windows 8 application that works fine with it's webservice.

I am trying to build a mobile app in Xamarin Forms that utilises this existing webservice. When I create a Service Reference to this webservice I don't get any errors and the reference is created. However, the functions created in my new Xamarin Forms app do not always replicate those created in the existing App. e.g.

Existing App:

```
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<CompassESafe.eAuditService.DownloadAuditHeadersResponse> DownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlAsync(CompassESafe.eAuditService.DownloadAuditHeadersRequest request) {
    return base.Channel.DownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlAsync(request);
}
```

Xamarin Forms:

```
public void DownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlAsync(eAudit.eAuditService.DownloadAuditHeadersRequest request) {
    this.DownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlAsync(request, null);    
}
```

As you can see, the return type is completely different, it has been changed to void, so obviously I cannot use this as I expected to.

Is there something I am doing wrong when I create a service reference in Xamarin Forms (or a PCL). As a test, I removed the reference from the existing project and re-added it, and it gets created as expected. I only have this problem in my Xamarin project.

Can I do this in Xamarin Forms using PCL or do I need to use a shared project? Or will Xamarin not allow this at all?

Edit - More info:
As stated the new auto-generated function doesn't return the required type. These functions exist that seem to return what I need but I'm not sure how to use them, can anyone shed any light please?

```
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    eAudit.eAuditService.DownloadAuditHeadersResponse eAudit.eAuditService.IDeviceService.EndDownloadAuditHeadersAsXml(System.IAsyncResult result) {
        return base.Channel.EndDownloadAuditHeadersAsXml(result);
    }

    private System.IAsyncResult OnBeginDownloadAuditHeadersAsXml(object[] inValues, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState) {
        eAudit.eAuditService.DownloadAuditHeadersRequest request = ((eAudit.eAuditService.DownloadAuditHeadersRequest)(inValues[0]));
        return ((eAudit.eAuditService.IDeviceService)(this)).BeginDownloadAuditHeadersAsXml(request, callback, asyncState);
    }

    private object[] OnEndDownloadAuditHeadersAsXml(System.IAsyncResult result) {
        eAudit.eAuditService.DownloadAuditHeadersResponse retVal = ((eAudit.eAuditService.IDeviceService)(this)).EndDownloadAuditHeadersAsXml(result);
        return new object[] {
                retVal};
    }

    private void OnDownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlCompleted(object state) {
        if ((this.DownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlCompleted != null)) {
            InvokeAsyncCompletedEventArgs e = ((InvokeAsyncCompletedEventArgs)(state));
            this.DownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlCompleted(this, new DownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlCompletedEventArgs(e.Results, e.Error, e.Cancelled, e.UserState));
        }
    }

    public void DownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlAsync(eAudit.eAuditService.DownloadAuditHeadersRequest request) {
        this.DownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlAsync(request, null);
    }

    public void DownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlAsync(eAudit.eAuditService.DownloadAuditHeadersRequest request, object userState) {
        if ((this.onBeginDownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlDelegate == null)) {
            this.onBeginDownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlDelegate = new BeginOperationDelegate(this.OnBeginDownloadAuditHeadersAsXml);
        }
        if ((this.onEndDownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlDelegate == null)) {
            this.onEndDownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlDelegate = new EndOperationDelegate(this.OnEndDownloadAuditHeadersAsXml);
        }
        if ((this.onDownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlCompletedDelegate == null)) {
            this.onDownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlCompletedDelegate = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OnDownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlCompleted);
        }
        base.InvokeAsync(this.onBeginDownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlDelegate, new object[] {
                    request}, this.onEndDownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlDelegate, this.onDownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlCompletedDelegate, userState);
    }
```

Comment: That's probably just an older way to do async. Instead of Task you get a callback. Which you might wrap in Task if you wish to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm not exactly sure what you mean, could you possibly provide an example please?

Comment: Are there methods like EndDownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlAsync, or does DownloadAuditHeadersRequest have something like that?

Comment: Added more info to the question - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so after a lot of trying random stuff to use the new code generated from the webservice, it seems the answer is actually pretty simple - I've never used delegates before so it was something new to me.

```
service.DownloadAuditHeadersResponse headersResponse = null;
_serviceClient.DownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlCompleted += delegate(object o, eServ.service.DownloadAuditHeadersAsXmlCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    headersResponse = args.Result;
};
```

so instead of calling a function to return the required object directly, you subscribe to the DownloadXxxCompleted event which returns the object.